# Making A Bot In Python

Tags: python, bots, mouse

I was making a bot that would basically keep the left mouse button clicked or unclicked based on a toggle. I get it to work but then it started lagging my entire computer so I didn't take it one step further, being scared to burn my PC, how It happened to my phone one year ago. So we are finally here asking you guys for some optimization to my project.
Code:

```
import keyboard
import win32api, win32con
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
mouse = Controller()
play=False

def toggle():
    global play
    if play==False:
        play=True
    else:
        play=False
keyboard.add_hotkey('home',toggle)
played=False
while True:
    if play==True and played==False:
        played=True
        mouse.press(Button.left)
    elif play==False:
        mouse.release(Button.left)
        played=False
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `time.sleep()` or something to wait between each loop because your while statement is running again and again without any pauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can slow the while loop by inserting a sleep function in it. To do this, import the module time and call the function time.sleep(ms) in your while loop. It will be less reactive but you can set a sleep time of only a few ms and it will be better because the program will not be running at full speed all the time.